# What does it mean (late) in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> A senior director in the Civil Aviation Authority of Thailand said [on June 20] that international flights were not likely to resume in Thailand until late September.

The late september mean 30/Sep? Or the 4th week on Sep?

Comment: The latter part of the month, so approximately the fourth week. Sept. 30th would be _the end of September_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early/mid-/late aren't set in stone, but let's say we have a 30-day month, and only the three most common adjectives to describe the stages within that month. You could then divide those 30 days into three equal parts (because we are using three temporal indicators), and you could then attribute "early" to the first, "mid-" to the second, and "late" to the final part.

If that is how we choose to divide the time period, "late September" just refers to the last 33% of that month, i.e. days 21-30.

(I have intentionally not divided the month into weeks.)